# Kibana - Average Count per Unique Field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a field, CRAB_Workflow, and I want to split the records over this field and count how many have a given value.

For example, CRAB_Workflow may have the following counts and values (I made up the counts so life is easy!),

```
CNT  STR
1    160325_174007:jalimena_crab_HLTPhysics_HaloStudy
2    160325_185554:afiqaize_crab_qcd15
3    160325_190029:afiqaize_crab_qcd80-0
4    160325_190434:afiqaize_crab_z1ll-1
1    160325_190806:afiqaize_crab_qcd50-0
2    160325_214052:alebihan_crab_TTplusJets_madgraph_signal
3    160326_105703:rdewanje_crab_ggH160_NTupleOnly
4    160327_144729:lecriste_crab_official_MC_noPtEtaCuts_nMCB0
1    160327_153516:cgalloni_crab_Trigger_HLTPhysics4_v3_Prescale
2    160328_161746:afiqaize_crab_qcd15
3    160328_161932:afiqaize_crab_qcd30-1
4    160328_162639:afiqaize_crab_z1ll-1
```

I want to count all the records that have one of those given value. Then average that count over all CRAB_Workflow values.

The numbers I would be looking for is (average and variance)

avg = 3*(1 + 2 + 3 + 4)/12 = 2.5

var = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use “**Data Table**” as the visualization form. Choose “**Count**” as the metric and for choose “**Split Rows**” for buckets. Use “**Terms**” for aggregation and then choose CRAB_Workflow (as in your specific question) as the field.

[Example in Kibana dashboard for data table visulization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73qLn.png)

After you get the data table, you can export the raw data and calculate the average count or other statistics across different Crab_Workflow values.

There may be a way to show statistics (average or variance, etc) for generated histogram or data tables in Kibana automatically, but I am not sure whether it is doable. Other people may have a better idea on that.